# Making webdriverio to wait for an element using webdriverio's waitUntil()?

Tags: automated-tests, wait, webdriver-io

Hello People does anyone know how to implement Webdriverio's waitUntil *(explicit wait)* to see if an element is existing?

to check if an element is existing we have the following:

```
browser.waitForExist(selector, timeout)
```

which after timeout will return a true of false depending upon if the element existed in the dom.

By that logic:

```
browser.waitUntil( function(){
   return browser.waitForExist(selector) == 'true')
},timeout,'element failed to exist')
```

should work right?

Answer (score 0):

I have the below code to identify whether an element exist or not using `waitUntil` in wdio.

```
browser.waitUntil(function(){
            return browser.elements(NAVIGATION_ICONS).value.length > 0;
        }, 15000, 'The navigation icon are not there');
```

The variable `NAVIGATION_ICONS` is an xpath.

Hope this helps.

Thank you,
Naveen.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [isExisting()](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/isExisting.html)

```
browser.waitUntil( function(){
    return selector.isExisting())
},timeout,'element failed to exist')
```